# Synchronous testing TypedActors

Tags: scala, akka

Is there any way to make my TypedActor calls synchronous? Im looking for some solution like TestActorRef for traditional Actors. I tried `.withDispatcher(CallingThreadDispatcher.Id)` but it works nondeterministic.

**Example:**

```
import akka.actor.{TypedActor, ActorSystem, TypedProps}
import akka.testkit.CallingThreadDispatcher
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, WordSpec}

class FooTest extends WordSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll{
  trait Foo {
    def foo():Unit
  }

  class Bar {
    def bar():String = "bar"
  }

  class FooActor(bar: Bar) extends Foo {
    override def foo(): Unit = println(bar.bar())
  }

  val barSpy = Mockito.spy(new Bar)
  val typedProps = TypedProps(classOf[Foo], new FooActor(barSpy)).withDispatcher(CallingThreadDispatcher.Id)
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("FooTest")



  "FooActor" should {
    "call Bar#bar() when foo is called" in {
      val fooActor : Foo = TypedActor(actorSystem).typedActorOf(typedProps)
      fooActor.foo()
      Mockito.verify(barSpy).bar()
    }
  }

  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = actorSystem.shutdown()
}
```

runned twice give both, positive and negative, result

Comment: By synchronous, do you mean "have it perform the work in the same thread as the caller?" I think it might help if you could provide samples of some code, what you're expecting, and why dispatching to a different thread is problematic.

Comment: By synchronous I mean perform actions in same order I call them(on all objects, not just actor), just like traditional methods. My problems are mocks, which calls cannot be verified because one time it is ok, next time it says that method wasnt called. Is it clear or should I provide some example?

Comment: I presume your typed-actor calls that are not being seen as called by your mocking library return Unit?

Comment: Both the typed actor proxy object and your mock should implement the same interface; why don't you just provide your mock to the code to use, rather than a typed actor? Your code shouldn't be any the wiser.

Comment: I provide mock to the actor, I call the actor, actor calls mock, I verify if mock was called. I will provide example in few hours.

Comment: Why use the actor at all in your test? Why not just provide the object directly? All the type actors macro does is define a delegator. If you want it done in the same thread, then why not just call your implementation directly?

Comment: Another thing you could try is to shut down your ActorSystem; See http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2 - you can send a poison pill to all actors and then have an event fire when every actor has processed that poison pill; since messages in akka are guaranteed to be ordered, you could wait for them all to die before running your mock expectations.

Comment: About using straight implementation: in my actor I use TypedActor.context  internally and it throws exception when called outside proper initialisation context. Thanks for shutdowning trick, I will check it, but it is more a walkaround than solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some workaround I've found. Not perfect but usable.

```
trait TestFoo {
  def foo_Sync() :Int 
}

class TestFooActor extends FooActor with TestFoo {
  def foo_Sync() :Int = {super.foo();1}
}
```

We use this trait instead of Foo in tests. Returning value make this call synchronous.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure that I full understand you but IIUC than you can use the expectMSG method to hold till the actor will complete.

```
case class Greeting(msg:String)
class FooActor(replyTo: ActorRef) extends Actor{
def receive = {
case Message(m) => replyTo ! Message("Hello "+m)
}
}
 "Greetings must be sent in a particular order" in{ 
 val foo = system.actorOf(Props(new FooActor()), "foo")
 foo ! Greeting("Sir")
 expectMsg(Greeting("Hello Sir"))
 filter ! "bla bla" //not a Greeting
 expectNoMsg
 foo ! Greeting("Foo")
 foo ! Greeting("Bar")
 expectMsg(Greeting("Hello Foo"))
 expectMsg(Greeting("Hello Bar"))
}
```

the expectMsg and the expectNoMsg wait to the actor completes or timeout 
if you do not want to use actorRef as a parameter to your Actor class (i.e replayTo) you can use intercept , but you need to make sure to use the single threaded environment in your tests 
something like this :

```
val foo = system.actorOf(Props[Foo].withDispatcher(CallingThreadDispatcher.Id) )
```

Comment: But the whole thing was about TypedActors, not traditional